# Am I catching the downloadURL properly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
var someRandomURL = "";    
var task = storageRef.put(file);
              task.on('state_changed',
                  function progress(snapshot) {
                    var percentageUploaded = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                  //  uploader.value = percentageUploaded;
                  },
                  function error(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  },
                  function complete() {
                    console.log("Upload completed successfully!");
                    somRandomURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
                  }
              );
```

This what I've done to capture the downloadURL of the image that I've uploaded, it's being uploaded properly but I'm not able to fetch the downloadURL. Can I know where I'm going wrong or am I misusing the downloadURL property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var percentageUploaded = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100; //check if its' 100% then get the download url like below,
 if(percentageUploaded ==100){
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        someRandomURL =url; //here you'll get the download url once the file is uploaded.
     })
 }
```

See this [Stackoverflow answer for Getting download url.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421276/how-can-i-add-firebase-storage-to-my-web-app/41696658#41696658)

[Getting Started with Firebase Storage on the Web - Firecasts by firebase channel from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU&index=21&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX). I hope this helps you.

Added [JSfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/80m8L653/1/).

Comment: Yeah, before that I shall show you the code for storageRef, I guess that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In  your codepen, just take storage.child("").getDownloadUrl().then(function(url){ }). instead of this add storageRef.getDownloadUrl(). Because you're putting the file in storageRef reference so that the reference will get the downloadUrl for you. See my jsfiddle example for clear idea

Comment: yup. I realized that after i sent the code to you. Thanks for the help though. I'm getting the url now. all's well. thanks again