# Stock user profile photo for newly created users

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

When users register, they are able to login to their accounts and the app will immediately navigate them to the customize profile page so they can finish registering. One thing that I would like to do though, is to have a generic profile photo (like a silhouette or something like that). Here is the basic html code for the page in which I would like to display it. The variables are pulling from the "profile" table in firebase, and I assign them values in the profile-page.ts. Right now the image is just coming from a folder in the solution...

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title center>{{groupName}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="has-header" padding>
  <div class="list card">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar>
            <img src="../../../assets/imgs/stockGroup.jpg">
        </ion-avatar>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>{{groupHandle}}</h2>
      <p>{{groupArea}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">
      <p>Image goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ion-button full color="dark" (click)="onGoToHomepage()"> Home </button>
  <hr>
  <button ion-button full color="dark"> View Group </button>
</ion-content>
```

What would be the correct way to set something like this up? I was thinking I could create a variable like {{profilePhoto}} and give it a value through a getUserProfilePhoto() function.

1. Is it okay to have a stock photo inside the solution, and then after an account is created load it into firebase somehow as that users profile photo? (this of course can be updated and overwritten if they decide to update it)
2. Where in firebase do photos get stored and how do they correlate to that unique uid?
3. Overall, what is the best workflow for something like this? I understand how simple text values are read and written in a firebase table but images are obviously different.

Thanks!

Comment: You could upload this placeholder profile image into Storage and then when the user sets up a profile and does not select an custom image for their profile photo, set the URL of the placeholder image as their profile photo URL. This way every user has a URL for their profile photo whether or not they have uploaded a personal one. You also do not have to check whether or not they have one, just use the URL that comes from the Document.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding you're looking for store the image of the logged user and then display it. If it's so may be i can help you out.

1. Logging a user

   a. **Google**, **facebook** and **twitter** using firebase authentication will give you the user profile picture as soon they login. So you can store the profile image under the user tree like below image.

[image: User Tree sample]

As you can see the image, i have user tree under that a userId in that, the user photoUrl.

b. **Email/password** firebase authentication method won't give you any user photo so for that you can use your default like something.

You can use firebase storage for uploading user photo and downloading the image. See below code for how to upload the user image into fb storage.

```
var file=e.target.files[0]; // get the image
var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref('firebase').child(file.name);
var task=storageRef.put(file);

task.on('state_changed',function progress(snapshot){
   var percentage=( snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes )*100; // using the percentage you can show a progess bar in the client if you wish.
   if (percentage==100){
     storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) { // here you'll get the image's url as soon it's uploaded to the fb storage.
            updateUserPhoto(url, file.name) // call a function to update the user photo.                
     });
   }
```

[See this post on how to upload image to storage after user selects a photo and press upload function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696658/6926744)

```
updateUserPhoto = function(url,imageName){
     var updateRef = {}        
     updateRef ['/user/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/photoUrl'] = url;
     updateRef ['/user/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/imageName'] = imageName // you can use the imageName key and value when a user uploads a new photo so you can use this imageName and refer it to the storage ref and delete the old and upload the newer one.
     firebase.database().ref().update(updateRef) // this is method is called multipath update. Note it returns a promise.
}
```

Note : You're using ionic means you can use angularfireStorage [refer this link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md)

Hope this gives you idea about how to store image of a logged user in the database and how to upload image to storage and make use of it.

Have a great day